# I have CollectionView cells in TableViewCells. I am facing issue in adjusting UIImageView width according to different simluators

Tags: swift, uitableview, uicollectionview

I have used CGSize(width: 370, height: 240) in collection view layout function sizeForItemAt which is not dynamic. Width:370 is perfect for iPhone 12/Pro but not for other cases. Hence I'm getting the output below:- [iPhone Mini Simulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8hxFo.png)

My extension in file are:

```
extension EventAttendTableCell : UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout,UICollectionViewDelegate,UICollectionViewDataSource{
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    eventAttendArray.count
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    guard let cell = collectionViewEventAttend.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "EventAttendCollectionCell", for: indexPath) as? EventAttendCollectionCell else {fatalError("Error to create TableViewCell")}
    
    let attendData = eventAttendArray[indexPath.row]
    cell.imgAttend.image = UIImage(named: attendData.imgEventAttendModel)
    cell.lblAttend1.text = attendData.lblEventAttendModelTop
    cell.lblAttend2.text = attendData.lblEventAttendModelMiddle
    cell.lblAttend3.text = attendData.lblEventAttendModelBottom
    
    
    return cell
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    20
}
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    20
}
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    return CGSize(width: 370, height: 240)
}


}
```

"eventAttendArray" is the Data array from the Model file.

Comment: You could use the collection view its width minus some margin as the width instead of the static 370.

Comment: Did you put some constraints on the cell contents for imgAttend, labels, and others view in your custom cell ? There may be a static or minimum size which cause problem.

Comment: @PtitXav yes I have used constraints on cell items. But isn't that issue of collectionView cell as a whole where cell width is not equal to simulator width?

Comment: @LloydKeijzer I don't get it. Aren't the margins different for every type of device? Sorry, I'm new to iOS development.

Comment: @ChetanjeevSinghBains The collection view it self is a view with a frame. That frame has a size property that holds the width of the collection view. On iPhone 11 that could be 300 width as on a iPad that could be 700 width. You could use that width minus 40 for instance to always have your cell be the full width of your collection view minus 40 which is the margin.

`return CGSize(width: collectionView.frame.size.width - 40, height: 240)`

Comment: @LloydKeijzer Okay got it. Thanks!